# Rename multiple computers

Tags: excel, function, csv, batch-file, batch-rename

Using netdom command I've successfully changed the host name on some systems.

**netdom renamecomputer OLDNAME /newname:NEWNAME /userd:Domain\DomainID /passwordd:* /force**

as I need to change name of hundred of systems.
So I've added a excel/csv file which will have 2 columns 'oldName' and 'NewName' respectively.

I have tried to create a function which calls the above mentioned command line with arguments(from each row in excel/csv file).

Powershell code

```
function renameAndReboot([string]$computer, [string]$newname)
{
        $comp = gwmi win32_computersystem  -computer $computer
        $os   = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computer $computer

        $comp.Rename($newname)
        $os.Reboot()
    }

Import-Csv mylist.csv

foreach ($entry in $list)
{
    renameAndReboot($entry.oldname,$entry.newname)
 }
```

I need to have same functionality in Batch script.

Basically i want to know how to import excel in batch file and execute each row.

can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: Since you said `I have tried to create a function which calls the above mentioned command line with arguments(from each row in excel/csv file)`, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31284582/edit) and add the code of that function.

Comment: Hi @ekad .. i made changes.
i had code in powershell and need same in batch script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FOR` to loop over all the lines of your CSV file and parse them delimited by commas.

Read `HELP FOR` and try this

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (mylist.csv) do (
  echo netdom renamecomputer %%a /newname:%%b /force
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Microsoft's MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer

Example #3

```
PS C:\> $a = Import-Csv ServerNames.csv -Header OldName, NewName
PS C:\> Foreach ( $Server in $a ) {Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Server.OldName -NewName $Server.NewName -DomainCredential Domain01\Admin01 -Force -Restart}
```